# AngularJS $routeProvider templates not showing up in ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-view, route-provider

Here is my folder structure:

```
public
--js
----controllers
------aController.js
------bController.js
----app.js
----router.js
--styles
----a.css
----b.css
--html
----a.html
----b.html
--index.html
```

In my index.html file I have:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

In my router.js file I have:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/a', {
        controller: 'aController',
        templateURL: 'html/a.html',
        css: 'styles/a.css'
    })
    .when('/b', {
        controller: 'bController',
        templateUrl: 'html/b.html',
        css: 'styles/b.css'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/a'
    });
}]);
```

In a.html and b.html I just have a div with the letter inside. ie.:

```
<p>a</p>
```

So when I load the page I expect to see an "a" but all I see is empty space. When I inspect the element, it shows `<!-- ngview -->`. I tested my routing and it seems to navigate to the right address, but why isn't my template showing up / why is my ng-view commented out? I tried both running from localhost and opening it in the web browser to the same effect.

EDIT: If it matters, I'm not getting any console errors and the path I'm seeing upon startup is:

.../appFolder/public/index.html#/a

Comment: Did you check the folder name? Looks like the templates are present in a directory named `html` and you are providing a wrong URL to `templateUrl`.

Comment: @Madhukar yes sorry, there was some mistakes in my original question, please see my edits

Comment: are there any console errors?

Comment: @war1oc no console errors, however if I manually navigate to ...index.html#/b, I get "GET /b.html" Error (404): "Not found". But when it's just at index.html#/a, I don't get any errors

Comment: Its related to path error for your view file you need to add path according to your base path

Comment: @NiketanRaval what should the paths be?

Comment: path should be ../../html/a.html try this it will works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... my paths were fine. However, I capitalized the "R" in templateURl... There is also no css property on the routeprovider object. Silly typos... Thanks for everyone's help though!

Answer (score 0):

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/a', {
        controller: 'aController',
        templateURL: '/html/a.html',
        css: '/styles/a.css'
    })
    .when('/b', {
        controller: 'bController',
        templateUrl: '/html/b.html',
        css: '/styles/b.css'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/a'
    });
}]);
```

Your router.js file seems to be inside the `js` folder, and your paths in the routes are thus invalid. Please check the paths in the code snippet above.

Comment: Yes, router.js file is inside the js folder, but changing the paths to the above didn't solve it for me...